# Accessing the Gdk area after import Gtk and closing a window

Tags: python, window, destroy, gtk3, gdk

I found myself in the situation where I needed to close a window which I had subclassed from `Gtk.Window`. I was connecting the window.destroy event to close the window initially to `Gtk.main_quit` for testing, but when I loaded the module into my main program, I couldn't do it that way, of course, without closing the main program. When I wrote a function, I stupidly called the `window.destroy()` method which, stupid of me, resulted in a max recursion error. So, I decided to connect a 'delete-event' and then call the `window.destroy()` which still recursed because (as I learned) a destroy event calls delete-event. So, I connected the destroy event to a function and tried to call:

```
window.emit('delete-event')
```

which worked, but resulted in an error wanting another parameter. Researching, I learned it needed to be something like this from gtk2:

```
window.emit("delete-event", gtk.gdk.Event(gtk.gdk.DELETE))
```

I can't find `Gdk` under `Gtk` like I can find `gdk` under `gtk`. I don't like this. I imported Gdk and `Gdk.Event` is found, but no equivalent to the `gtk.gdk.DELETE variable`. I did a:

```
l = dir(Gdk)
for i in l:
    if 'DELETE' in i:
        print(i)
```

and came up with no DELETE variable defined in Gdk.

How can we access Gdk from Gtk? If not, how do we translate these gtk.gdk... things when they don't exist under Gdk?

Ultimately, I just did:

```
del window
```

to do what I needed to do, but I still would like to know how to do the emit signal above in Gtk3 for learning purposes.

Thanks,

Narnie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `gtk.gdk` in GTK 3, all of that functionality, or its equivalent, *must* be available using `from gi.repository import Gdk`. The previous `gtk.gdk` hierarchy was actually for convenience, but didn't make any sense because GDK is a completely independent package and is not part of GTK. The new organization makes more sense because the hierarchy and variable names are exactly the same as in the C, Javascript, etc. APIs.

In this case, `gtk.gdk.DELETE` is available as `Gdk.EventType.DELETE`, so you should be able to do

```
window.emit('delete-event', Gdk.Event(Gdk.EventType.DELETE))
```

However, [you are not supposed to emit event signals yourself](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-event), so it would be better to do:

```
window.event(Gdk.Event(Gdk.EventType.DELETE))
```

Or even better, don't connect to the event at all in your module. Then you can use `window.destroy()` without a recursion error. Connect to the destroy signal in your main program, then you can simply call `Gtk.main_quit`.

Comment: The first part really helps. I just couldn't find it. The latter part won't work, because I'm not wanting a `Gtk.main_quit` from closing out the window. How can I close the window when requested by the user (assuming the request is from X-ing out the window and not clicking a close button) without connecting to the `destroy` or `delete-event` signals?

Comment: Also, thank for letting me know about how to "emit" without "emitting" myself but through `Window.event`. I am still pretty early in using GUIs, so this are little nuggets that really help. I'm grateful for people who are very facile helping people like me :)

Comment: Well, if the user clicks the X button, then the window gets the `delete-event` signal, which should close and destroy the window by default, without you having to do anything. I guess I don't understand your follow-up question?